# Call in Android application shows add contact dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, call, android-contacts

I'm using this code for calling, in Android application:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);    
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + call.Number));   
startActivity(callIntent);
```

but I obtain a dialog like this:

[image]

Why no call is make?

P.s: I'm using a Tablet (Acer Iconia A501), not a smartphone.

Comment: Check your manifest file

Comment: have you gave permission in manifest file?<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Comment: it's because you can't call from this tablet ...

Comment: how can I solve this problem?

Comment: you need to change device ... http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1311894

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Make sure :

**call to :**

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" +mEditText_number.getText())));
```

**Add permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```