# Call from tablet in android application

Tags: android, android-intent, tablet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call in Android application shows add contact dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624599/call-in-android-application-shows-add-contact-dialog)

How can I make a call in android application, from tablet (Acer ICONIA TAB A501)?

I tried whit thi code:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);    
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + call.Number));   
startActivity(callIntent);
```

but this open a dialog asking for adding the telephone number to my contacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using  ACTION_DIAL  instead     http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1311894

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this on Acer iconia. Some device doesnt supports calling facility(over 2g or 3g network), atleast not this device. This could be somehow due to some hardware problem or it might be locked.